# Failed to instantiate component or class "yii\gii\Module"

Tags: php, yii2

I just created new Yii 2 application on Mac os. PHP version I'm using is version `7.3`. Composer install worked correctly but when I try to start the app using the command `php yii serve` I get the following error.

```
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Failed to instantiate component or class "yii\gii\Module".'

in /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:449

Stack trace:
#0 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(374): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('yii\\gii\\Module')
#1 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build('yii\\gii\\Module', Array, Array)
#2 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('yii\\gii\\Module', Array, Array)
#3 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(427): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array, Array)
#4 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(315): yii\base\Module->getModule('gii')
#5 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(273): yii\base\Application->bootstrap()
#6 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(124): yii\base\Application->init()
#7 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): yii\console\Application->init()
#8 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#9 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(89): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#10 /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/lms/yii(19): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#11 {main}
```

When I run composer update I get more errors like this

```
 ailed to extract yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap: (9) unzip -qq  '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-26e4a5cb7b14ec2c9244cc7f29b77c9d' -d '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/63a3aea5'
    
    unzip:  cannot find or open /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-26e4a5cb7b14ec2c9244cc7f29b77c9d.
    
        This most likely is due to a custom installer plugin not handling the returned Promise from the downloader
        See https://github.com/composer/installers/commit/5006d0c28730ade233a8f42ec31ac68fb1c5c9bb for an example fix
        Failed to extract yiisoft/yii2-debug: (9) unzip -qq  '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-ee4e9bc3f65bc1e6d3bb29c47448147f' -d '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/c3a14115'

unzip:  cannot find or open /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-ee4e9bc3f65bc1e6d3bb29c47448147f.

    This most likely is due to a custom installer plugin not handling the returned Promise from the downloader
    See https://github.com/composer/installers/commit/5006d0c28730ade233a8f42ec31ac68fb1c5c9bb for an example fix
    Failed to extract yiisoft/yii2-faker: (9) unzip -qq  '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-adfed1b28e8eb6386664db1dc98849ab' -d '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/d8990f9a'

unzip:  cannot find or open /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-adfed1b28e8eb6386664db1dc98849ab.

    This most likely is due to a custom installer plugin not handling the returned Promise from the downloader
    See https://github.com/composer/installers/commit/5006d0c28730ade233a8f42ec31ac68fb1c5c9bb for an example fix
    Failed to extract yiisoft/yii2-gii: (9) unzip -qq  '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-a51d0a4cc1fef91725fe727eb3a41a43' -d '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/eaed0437'

unzip:  cannot find or open /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-a51d0a4cc1fef91725fe727eb3a41a43.

    This most likely is due to a custom installer plugin not handling the returned Promise from the downloader
    See https://github.com/composer/installers/commit/5006d0c28730ade233a8f42ec31ac68fb1c5c9bb for an example fix
    Failed to extract yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer: (9) unzip -qq  '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-d3e0c5f68aded7a5357259ffde56f5ea' -d '/Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/3514a4ce'

unzip:  cannot find or open /Users/krishnadas/Desktop/thejas/basic/vendor/composer/tmp-d3e0c5f68aded7a5357259ffde56f5ea.

    This most likely is due to a custom installer plugin not handling the returned Promise from the downloader
    See https://github.com/composer/installers/commit/5006d0c28730ade233a8f42ec31ac68fb1c5c9bb for an example fix`
```

Comment: can you provide some configs? You are using basic or advanced template?

Comment: I'm using basic template, nothing has been changed it is just a fresh installation as in the yii2 installation set up. Is there anything to be changed before running serve?

Comment: no, not really, only wanted to ask. Which url have you called? can you show your steps?
Used this guide? https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation

Have tested it and it works fine. The only difference, i have used php7.4

Comment: I'm using the same url as you commented.

Comment: ok, tested it with PHP 7.3.19 no problems. 
Could you execute `composer update` in your working directory

Comment: Same result run composer update, also upgraded php to version 7.4. Which os are you using?

Comment: fedora, but it shouldn't be the reason

Comment: Updated the question please check those errors were not there early. I guess some of the modules are not getting installed.

Comment: Are you using Composer 2? Some plugins may not be compatible with Composer 2, you may need to upgrade them first. See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-composer/commit/ac0af9da5b4addd9fc6cf852fe66d65f6ac761cd

Comment: `Composer version 2.0-dev (2.0-dev+ae44a5963d18b61e0334295b005de7a4ee28aafc) 2020-06-22 08:54:38
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It finally worked when I downgraded composer to the latest stable version `1.10.7`. Version `2` has issues with some of the install items such as `gii`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You save my day...

Answer (score 0):

I update composer on the mac and fix the problem.
After install just

```
composer update
```